# Where can I see what print_r display on PHP?

Tags: php, android, mysql, xampp, slim

I have a `REST API` with `Android` and `Slim framework`. I'm using `XAMPP` to connect it with a MySQL database, .

I don't know where `print_r` is displayed.

The `api.php` file is in `C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\project\app\api\api.php`.

I get the following message when I try to access `localhost/project/app/api/api.php`:

> Access denied.

It's a message that I put with `define` function. In index.php:

```
define("CONSTANT",true);
```

In connect.php and api.php:

```
if(!defined("CONSTANT")) die("Access denied");
```

Comment: How are you requesting the script that does the `print_r`?

Comment: Maybe try `exit(print_r($myVar));`.

Comment: @Halcyon I have a folder on my `XAMPP` folder in which I have all the files of `Slim` and there it's where I connect it with the database.

Comment: it should be inside `htdocs` inside `XAMPP` folder for `print_r` to work

Comment: @MubinKhalid Yes, it is on `htdocs` folder inside `XAMPP` folder but inside `htdocs` folder I created a new folder named `project` in which I have my scripts and the connection.

Comment: then all set, please look at my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/32204526/2558525, if you've `print_r` in test.php then: go to `localhost/project/test.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, testing different options during some hours, I get the solution.

If you are changing three values in your `PUT` method of your `REST API`, for example, `name`, `description` and `idCar`, after setting their new values (that you send from your `Android application`) you can put on your `PHP script`:

```
print_r([$name,$description,$idCar]);
```

Here all it's equals than before. So, **how can you see what `print_r` it's displaying?**

After executing your `response` on your `Android application`, you can put these two lines:

```
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
String responseText = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
```

And then you can put a `Log` to see what it's displaying:

```
Log.d("response",responseText);
```

Now you will be able to see what `print_r` it's displaying.

Answer (score 0):

`print_r` is outputted to the file whereever it is called.  Just check the source of your web page and the output will be there somewhere.

If you need to find it quickly try echoing something unique above the `print_r`. E.g. `echo "I AM OVER HERE!!!";`

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you've a page `test.php` where you're using `print_r($stuff);`
and I assume that you've installed xampp in `C:\Program Files\xampp` and your code is inside here `C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\droidApp`

`droidApp` is folder where this file `test.php` is residing.

`test.php` can have

```
<?php
    print_r($stuff_you_want_to_print);
?>
```

go to this url from your browser

`localhost/droidApp/test.php`

just make sure your xampp is running before doing that.

Comment: It gives to me Access dennied. And have I run my APP before putting my url on the browser?

Comment: you can try, I'm not pretty sure about that. give it a hitch.

Comment: My `print_r` it's in one of the methods of my `Slim framework` (`put` method). I tried using the url executing my `api.php` when the APP it's using this method, but the message `Access dennied` doesn't change. Do you think why it happens?

Comment: Ok I saw that this message it's being show because I have a constant defined with `define` method and I have a `die` if it is not the constant value. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I use this way.

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Yes, but where I can see it? I'm not asking about how to use it, just where can I see the values that it displays.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Rest API extension of chrome:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en

In that you can hit the url of your service and can see all your `print_r` and `var_dump` values.

Comment: If I have `print_r([$name,$description,$idCar]);` and on the extension I see an array that has `Array( [0] =>  [1] => [2] =>) {"status":true}` then it means that the data it's not in the put method, right?

Comment: while hitting a url of your service you can also set the method (i.e. post, put, delete,get etc). Here in your code the array is showing what you have pass in `print_r` and the `{"status":true}` is showing what you have return at the end of your service, I think you have not `die` your code after `print_r`

Comment: One more think is there that main functionality of a function does not fully depend on `put` or `post` method, that is depend that how you have defined your function to act. (Basically we use `put` method for `update` and `post` for `insert`

Comment: Finally I got a solution to see what it was being sent (I post an answer) but I have a doubt, with your extension, have I set the url and then execute the part of my code in Android that use that url to see the values? Or execute the application before putting the url on the extension? Thanks!

Comment: that extension is used for the web developers who create the services, so they can test there services by hit the url in that extension. So basically when you create a service you can test that by putting the url in extension.

Comment: Yes but I already have my service in a local server. Is it only for web servers?

Comment: no you can also test your services on local server (i.e. localhost). You just need to put the url of your local service like http://localhost/my-services/service1 (you can set the method put, post, get etc)

Comment: Yes I did it but when I do this I get the output that I put in my first comment.

Answer (score -1):

print_r prints the specified variable to the screen, similar to the way the echo command does.  There's a second argument which is a boolean that is set to false by default.  If you set it to true, it will allow you to store the contents in a variable rather than print it to screen.

Thus,

```
print_r($_GET)
```

is the same as

```
$inputs = print_r($_GET,true);
echo $inputs;
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php for more information.

Comment: he is not asking about print_r, instead he is asking that where he can see the printed values